# Bootstrap grid/column responsive issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I plan to create a column like this:
When dekstop is always show at least one content,

1    2    3
content 1

When Mobile is always hide the content first:

1
2
3

after click eg #2

1
2
content 2
3

can view the [visual Sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf54J.jpg).

I've tried to do with hide and show with jQuery, but then it doesn't look smooth, and when on mobile screen enlarge to desktop view it have issue :(

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/cyapsl/pen/YrwKOj)

```js
function resize() {
  if ($(window).width() < 992) {
    $('.blue').removeClass('active');
    $(".features.purple, .features.blue, .features.grey").removeClass('active');
    $(".blue-cover").hide();
    $(".pruple-cover").hide();
    $(".grey-cover").hide();

  } else {
    $(".features.purple, .features.blue, .features.grey").removeClass('active');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(resize);
  resize();
});


$(".dekstop-grey").click(function() {
  $(".grey-cover").show();
  $(".greyarr").show();
  $(".blue-cover, .purple-cover, .bluearr, .purplearr").hide();
  $(".features.grey").addClass('active');
  $(".features.purple, .features.blue").removeClass('active');
});

$(".dekstop-blue").click(function() {
  $(".blue-cover").show();
  $(".bluearr").show();
  $(".grey-cover, .purple-cover, .greyarr .purplearr").hide();
  $(".features.blue").addClass('active');
  $(".features.purple, .features.grey").removeClass('active');
});


$(".dekstop-purple").click(function() {
  $(".purple-cover").show();
  $(".purplearr").show();
  $(".grey-cover, .blue-cover, .greyarr, .bluearr").hide();
  $(".features.purple").addClass('active');
  $(".features.blue, .features.grey").removeClass('active');
});

$(".fblue").click(function() {
  $(".blue-cover, .bluearr").show();
  $(".grey-cover, .purple-cover, .greyarr .purplearr").hide();
  $(".features.blue").addClass('active');
  $(".features.purple, .features.grey").removeClass('active');
});

$(".fpurple").click(function() {
  $(".purple-cover, .purplearrs").show();
  $(".grey-cover, .blue-cover, .greyarr, .bluearr").hide();
  $(".features.purple").addClass('active');
  $(".features.grey, .features.blue").removeClass('active');
});

$(".fgrey").click(function() {
  $(".grey-cover, .greyarr").show();
  $(".blue-cover, .purple-cover, .bluearr, .purplearr").hide();
  $(".features.grey").addClass('active');
  $(".features.purple, .features.blue").removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.three-feature {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.three-feature .arrowup {
  display: none;
}

.three-feature .blue-cover {
  background: blue;
  padding: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.three-feature .purple-cover {
  background: purple;
  padding: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.three-feature .grey-cover {
  background: grey;
  padding: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .three-feature .arrowup {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.three-feature .active .arrowup {
  display: inline-block;
}

.three-feature .features {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .three-feature .features {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    max-width: 320px;
  }
}

.three-feature .features.active.blue,
.three-feature .features:hover.blue {
  border-color: blue;
}

.three-feature .features.active.purple,
.three-feature .features:hover.purple {
  border-color: purple;
}

.three-feature .features.active.grey,
.three-feature .features:hover.grey {
  border-color: grey;
}

.three-feature .features.active .feature-inner.blue,
.three-feature .features:hover .feature-inner.blue {
  border-color: blue;
}

.three-feature .features.active .feature-inner.purple,
.three-feature .features:hover .feature-inner.purple {
  border-color: purple;
}

.three-feature .features.active .feature-inner.grey,
.three-feature .features:hover .feature-inner.grey {
  border-color: grey;
}

.three-feature .features .feature-inner {
  border: 3px dashed transparent;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.three-feature .features .feature-inner p {
  min-height: 72px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 15px 0;
  /* Extra Small */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .three-feature .features .feature-inner p {
    min-height: auto;
  }
}

.three-feature .features .feature-inner .icon {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 220px;
}

.three-feature .features .feature-inner .logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 153px;
}

.three-feature .colmn {
  /* Extra Small */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .three-feature .colmn {
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="cwrcover">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="three-feature">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 dekstop-blue active colmn text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <div class="features active blue center-block">
              <div class="feature-inner blue">
                <h1>Dekstop 01</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/blue/triangle-xxl.png" class="bluearr arrowup" style="max-width: 35px;" alt="">
          </div>
          <!--1-->
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 dekstop-purple colmn text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <div class="features purple center-block">
              <div class="feature-inner purple">
                <h1>Dekstop 02</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/purple/triangle-xxl.png" class="purplearr arrowup" style="max-width: 35px;" alt="">
          </div>
          <!--2-->
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 dekstop-grey colmn text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <div class="features grey center-block">
              <div class="feature-inner grey">
                <h1>Dekstop 03</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/gray/triangle-xxl.png" class="greyarr arrowup" style="max-width: 35px;" alt="">
          </div>
          <!--3-->
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 fblue colmn text-center hidden-lg hidden-md">
            <div class="features active blue center-block">
              <div class="feature-inner blue">
                <h1>MOBILE 01</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 blue-cover">
            <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/blue/triangle-xxl.png" class="bluearrow center-block hidden-lg hidden-md" alt="">
            <div id="featurevid" class="center-block blue">
              <div class="benefits">
                BLUE 01 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 colmn fpurple text-center hidden-lg hidden-md">
            <div class="features pink center-block">
              <div class="feature-inner purple">
                <h1>MOBILE 02</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--2-->
          <div class="col-xs-12 purple-cover" style="display: none;">
            <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/purple/triangle-xxl.png" class="purplearrow center-block hidden-lg hidden-md" alt="">
            <div id="featurevid" class="center-block purple">
              <div class="benefits">
                purple 01 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Purple cover Dekstop-->
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 colmn fgrey text-center hidden-lg hidden-md">
            <div class="features yellow center-block">
              <div class="feature-inner grey">
                <h1>MOBILE 03</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--3-->
          <div class="col-xs-12 grey-cover" style="display: none;">
            <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/grey/triangle-xxl.png" class="greyarrow center-block hidden-lg hidden-md" alt="">
            <div id="featurevid" class="center-block grey">
              <div class="benefits">
                GREY 01 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Grey Dekstop-->
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I do not see any problem... What's wrong exactly?

Comment: It's doesn't work smoothly especially when i resize the browser, sometime got extra arrow sometime arrow disable :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
});
```

You can't call `resize()` on `document.ready`, because your resize method is checking for `window width` less than 992 & hiding `.blue-cover`.

Please remove the `resize` method from `document.ready`, it should be

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(window).resize(resize);
});
```

`resize` method will only be called when you `resize your browser`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution, but when i use mobile to testing, the content will auto hide when i scroll down :(